# Avoid comment style for URLs in code listings

Tags: listings, color, comments

I using the following settings for code listings.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{language=Java,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{Green}\ttfamily,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    upquote=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowskip=3em,
    belowcaptionskip=.25\baselineskip
}
```

The actual code listing contains comments as well as URLs. How can I ensure that only the comment will be colored with `commentstyle` but not the URL that contains a double slash `//` as well?

```
// This is a comment.
http://tex.stackexchange.com
```

In the example `tex.stackexchange.com` would be colored `Green`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
morecomment=[l][basicstyle]{http://},
```

which gives

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\lstset{language=Java,
    keywordstyle=\color{RoyalBlue},
    basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    upquote=true,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=8pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ftff,
    frame=single,
    belowskip=3em,
    belowcaptionskip=.25\baselineskip,
    morecomment=[l][basicstyle]{http://}, %<---- NEW BIT!
}


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
// This is a comment.
http://tex.stackexchange.com
hello world
// another comment http://tex.stackexchange.com
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```